# Write An Generic Function can take Array[Array[T]] or List[List[T]] or List[Array[T]] or SeqLike[SeqLike[T]] as parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

How to write a function can take  Array[Array[T]] or List[List[T]] or List[Array[T]] or SeqLike[SeqLike[T]] as parameter?

Some function like:

`def transposeMatrix[T, S <% Seq[T], SS <% Seq[S]](xss: SS): Seq[Seq[T]] = for (i <- xss.head.indices) yield for (xs <- xss) yield xs(i) 
val v = transposeMatrix(matrix)`

matrix is List[Array[String]], but matrix can be anyof Array[Array[T]] or List[List[T]] or List[Array[T]] or SeqLike[SeqLike[T]]

or in another way, very similar as `transpose` method of `GenericTraversableTemplate` trait of scala library

BTW : right now I got error "Error:(48, 26) type mismatch;
 found

```
: <:<[Nothing,Nothing]
 required: Array[String] => Seq[?]
  val v = transposeMatrix(matrix
```

)" during running

Comment: You need a lot more information than this. 1. There has to be more to the problem description than what you showed here, as that's not much of a problem, 2. You need to show what you've done first, this isn't a site that will wrote code for you when you haven't tried anything first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use higher kinds I guess, and play around with the lower bound to get the semantics you want. You can also enable `higherKinds` in `build.sbt` by explicitly passing `-language:higherKinds` to `scalacOptions`.

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

def test[
  M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X],
  Inner[Y] <: TraversableOnce[Y],
  T
](col: M[Inner[T]): Bla
```